# Want to display the text of the button clicked in adaptive cards

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have created a Teams bot and I have a few submit action buttons.
On clicking these buttons I would want to let the user know that the button has been clicked.
Im using adaptive cards and submit action.

```
card.Actions.Add(new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
            {
                Title = item.Key,
                Data = item.Value,
                DataJson = "{\"Type\": \"Sort\"}"

            });
```

On clicking the "sort button I want the bot postback "sort".
[image: on clicking "sort" I'm not able to see the word "Sort"]

This is how I see in teams
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to do this using the special "msteams" payload, and specifying "messageBack", or "imBack" as the message type, similar to this:

```
{
  "type": "Action.Submit",
  "title": "Click me for messageBack",
  "data": {
    "msteams": {
        "type": "messageBack",
        "displayText": "I clicked this button",
        "text": "text to bots",
        "value": "{\"bfKey\": \"bfVal\", \"conflictKey\": \"from value\"}"
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#example).

Because you're using C#, you'd need an actual class to represent this, so you could do something like:

```
public class msteams
{
   public string type {get; set;} = "messageBack";
   public string displayText {get; set;}
   public string text {get; set;}
   public string value {get; set;}
}
```

Then you would set it like this:

```
card.Actions.Add(new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
            {
                Title = item.Key,
                Data = new msTeams() { displayText = "...", ... }
            });
```

Obviously you could use attributes to change the name of the class, property names, etc. For a more simple approach, you can just the "imBack" option, which I've wrapped below with attributes as well:

```
    public class AdaptiveCardImBackButton
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; } = "imBack";

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I wrap that again, to get it to serialize the outer "msteams" attribute, as follows:

```
 public class AdaptiveCardImBackButtonContainer
    {
        [JsonProperty("msteams")]
        public AdaptiveCardImBackButton AdaptiveCardImBackButton { get; private set; }

        public AdaptiveCardImBackButtonContainer(string value)
        {
            AdaptiveCardImBackButton = new AdaptiveCardImBackButton() { Value = value };
        }
    }
```

The final usage in your code is really simple:

```
            card.Actions.Add(new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
            {
                Title = "sort",
                Data = new AdaptiveCardImBackButtonContainer("sort")
            });
```

Comment: @Elma Sarah Daniel, Does this answer your questions?

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT, no it did not work for me.

Comment: @hilton giesenow, no I'm still not able to see the button text. I have updated my question with the image from the Teams channel.

Comment: I have tried creating msteams class and 

`card.Actions.Add(new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
            {
                Title = item.Key,
                Data = new msTeams() { displayText = "...", ... }
            });`

But I'm still getting the same results( I'm not getting the postback text)

Comment: Please try with my updated code+classes. If the serialized result isn't EXACTLY right, it's ignored (and your looks like "msTeams" instead of "msteams", for instance)

Comment: @Elma : Please let us after you try Hilton's solution, if you still face issues.

Comment: @Manish-MSFT 
@HiltonGiesenow
I'm still facing the same issue.

`public class msteams
    {
        public string type { get; set; } = "messageBack";
        public string displayText { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }`

`card.Actions.Add(new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
            {
                Title = "Filter",
                Data = new msteams() { displayText = "Filter", text = "Filter", value= "{\"Type\": \"Filter\"}" }
            });'

Comment: it might not actually be rendering the "msteams" into the final output, only it's children - I had this issue a few days ago when I was testing. Please just try using the sample I put in my answer above.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Thanks, but I'm still not seeing any changes

Comment: please post code sample in your original question (update it)

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, thanks. It was my mistake, I got it working using JSON data.